# Defining POST parameters for configuring generic server for Tasks & Contexts management

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, tfs

I am trying to configure my Android studio to fetch work items from Team Foundation Server. However, TFS doesn't have a direct api for getting a list of work items and you need to do this through a query.. But the query needs to be put as a POST parameter .. I have been through the configuring window from top to bottom, but I can't find a way how to add a POST parameter to the request..

If that is not possible, is there some option to dynamically define the template variable we can use in the GET parameters? That way, I could retrieve a list of ids I am currently in need of and let the IDE update my tasks accordingly.

Can somebody advise?

Comment: Are you trying to use TFS REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of work items with REST API, please check the syntax below:

```
GET https://{instance}/defaultcollection/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version={version}[&ids={string}&fields={string}&asof={datetime}&$expand={enum{relations}]
```

More information, you can refer to:
https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items

Comment: Yes, but you need to know the specific ids, that you want to fetch .... That's where queries come to action, but to request a query I need to specify it in a POST parameter, which is exactly my problem..

Comment: So you query is not related to TFS, but how to implement your code? You may add more related tags to get better help.

Comment: Exactly.. well, this is entirely IDE problem, but I added tfs tag in case that somebody would know some other workaround how to get work items, without having to specify the ids... I know query API is the way to go, but the inability to specify POST parameter in the IDE is the problem here

Comment: On TFS side, you need either specify the ids to get a list of work items, or get work items using a query: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/wiql#GetworkitemsAflatquery